# Sorting a html list using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, sorting

I´m trying to sort a html list (dropdown menu format that gets filtered as I write something)

dropdown menu list appears when I click on search field

[image: 1]

```
<div class="search-block">
                    <!--<img class="searchimage" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/4dc88303-8015-467f-9334-2e63fdb63c75/9385963701556258272-16.png?v=1650523566208" alt="search image">-->
                    <input id="searchbar" type="text" value="" placeholder="  Search" onclick="myFunction();sort()" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
                    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

                        <ol id="list1">
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child1" target="_blank">New Born</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child2" target="_blank">Smash the Cake</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child3" target="_blank">Pregnancy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child4" target="_blank">Pre-Wedding</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child5" target="_blank">Family</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child6" target="_blank">Birthday</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child7" target="_blank">Professional</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child8" target="_blank">Social Media</a></li>
                        </ol>

                        <!-- TO DO: ADD ITEMS TO THE LIST-->
                    </div>  

                    <p class="copyright">&copy; 2022 Farias Carril Photography | Designed and built by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/daniel-carril-569a76131" style="color: #F1820B;" target="_blank">Daniel Carril</a></p>
                </div>
```

using JavaScript function.

However, it is not working. What am I missing?

I´m using usual sort algorithm for a simple list

```
function sort() {
  var list, i, switching, shouldSwitch;
  div = document.querySelector(".search-block");
  a = div.getElementsById("a");
  list = document.getElementById("list1");
  switching = true;
  while (switching)
  {
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i=0; i<(b.length - 1); i++){
      shouldSwitch = false;
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i+1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()){
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch)
    {
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i+1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Is this an academic exercise? Why aren't you using the built-in `sort` JavaScript function? Also, what's the "usual" algorithm for you? Maybe what's usual for you it's not for other people

Comment: As mentioned: use `.sort()` with a comparison function as argument, and then run `appendChild` for all the elements of the now-sorted list (which does not "add them a second time" because DOM nodes can only exist in one place, so appending them just moves them to the end of the list, one by one. Presto, sorted list)

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console? `a = div.getElementsById("a");` is pretty suspect. Did you mean getElementsByTagName ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName )?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is that getElementsById is not a method on the div tag so this causes the script to encounter an error and halt. The second issue is that calling innerHTML on the li tags will return something like `<a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child1" target="_blank">New Born</a>`, i.e. the result includes the HTML of the a tag inside the li tag. You can change innerHTML to textContent to get the text inside the a tag (alternatively you could grab the a tag and get its innerHTML).

```js
function sort() {
  var list, i, switching, shouldSwitch;
  div = document.querySelector(".search-block");
  // a = div.getElementsById("a");
  list = document.getElementById("list1");
  switching = true;
  while (switching)
  {
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i=0; i<(b.length - 1); i++){
      shouldSwitch = false;
      // textContent instead of innerHTML
      if (b[i].textContent.toLowerCase() > b[i+1].textContent.toLowerCase()){
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch)
    {
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i+1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="search-block">
                    <!--<img class="searchimage" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/4dc88303-8015-467f-9334-2e63fdb63c75/9385963701556258272-16.png?v=1650523566208" alt="search image">-->
                    <input id="searchbar" type="text" value="" placeholder="  Search" onclick="sort()" onkeyup="">
                    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

                        <ol id="list1">
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child1" target="_blank">New Born</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child2" target="_blank">Smash the Cake</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child3" target="_blank">Pregnancy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child4" target="_blank">Pre-Wedding</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child5" target="_blank">Family</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child6" target="_blank">Birthday</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child7" target="_blank">Professional</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gallery.html#gallery-main-grid-child8" target="_blank">Social Media</a></li>
                        </ol>

                        <!-- TO DO: ADD ITEMS TO THE LIST-->
                    </div>  

                    <p class="copyright">&copy; 2022 Farias Carril Photography | Designed and built by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/daniel-carril-569a76131" style="color: #F1820B;" target="_blank">Daniel Carril</a></p>
                </div>
```

- [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)